# Doctrine2, оптимизация выборки

Tags: php, doctrine2

Такая конструкция генерирует лишних 4 `SELECT` (запрос для каждой связующей записи). Как сделать что бы выполнялся один запрос с `LEFT JOIN`?

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('menu')
    ->addSelect('menu')
    ->leftJoin('menu.children', 'children')
    ->where('menu.parent IS NULL')
    ->orderBy('menu.position')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась написанием DQL запроса

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u, p FROM CmsUser u JOIN u.phonenumbers p');
```

[Ссылка на документацию по DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)